# The mean value of non-zero elements in each row of a sparse matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, statistics, sparse-matrix

In the following sparse matrix:

```
A=[1 1 1 3];
C = sparse(A',1:length(A),ones(length(A),1),4,4);
C =

   (1,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
   (1,3)        1
   (3,4)        1

>>full(C)

ans =

     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0
```

How could I compute the mean value of non-zero elements in each row? I couldn't use the built-in mean function of matlab on these sparse matrices.
I found [this similar question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/314575-how-to-find-the-median-of-nonzero-elements-in-each-row-of-sparse-matrix) and I can apply it to my problem

```
[row, ~, v] = find(C);
K>> rowmean = accumarray(row, v, [], @mean);
K>> rowmean 

rowmean =

     1
     0
     1
```

However, I would like to get zero value for the last row instead of this row being removed from the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Approach 1

You can specify the output size as the third input of [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[row, ~, v] = find(C);
rowmean = accumarray(row, v, [size(C,1), 1], @mean);
```

If desired, you can use the sixth input of `accumarray` to obtain `sparse` output:

```
rowmean = accumarray(row, v, [size(C,1), 1], @mean, 0, true);
```

### Approach 2

You can do something simpler like this. The result is `sparse`:

```
rowmean = sum(C, 2) ./ sum(C~=0, 2); % mean of nonzeros in each row, manually
rowmean(isnan(rowmean)) = 0; % replace NaN (resulting from 0/0) by 0
```